# ReplaceOneAsync() immediately after InsertOneAsync() not always working, even when journaled

Tags: c#, mongodb, journaling

On a single-instance MongoDB server, even with the write concern on the client set to journaled, one in every couple of thousand documents isn't replacable immediately after inserting.

I was under the impression that once journaled, documents are immediately available for querying.

The code below inserts a document, then updates the `DateModified` property of the document and tries to update the document based on the document's Id and the old value of that property.

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var r = Task.Run(MainAsync);

    Console.WriteLine("Inserting documents... Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
}

private static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("updateInsertedDocuments");

    var concern = new WriteConcern(journal: true);

    var collection = database.GetCollection<MyDocument>("docs").WithWriteConcern(concern);

    int errorCount = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;

    do
    {
        totalCount++;

        // Create and insert the document
        var document = new MyDocument
        {
            DateModified = DateTime.Now,
        };
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);

        // Save and update the modified date
        var oldDateModified = document.DateModified;
        document.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

        // Try to update the document by Id and the earlier DateModified
        var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(d => d.Id == document.Id && d.DateModified == oldDateModified, document);

        if (result.ModifiedCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {++errorCount}/{totalCount}: doc {document.Id} did not have DateModified {oldDateModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")}");

            await DoesItExist(collection, document, oldDateModified);
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

The code inserts at a rate of around 250 documents per second. One in around 1,000-15,000 calls to `ReplaceOneAsync(d => d.Id == document.Id && d.DateModified == oldDateModified, ...)` fails, as it returns a `ModifiedCount` of 0. The failure rate depends on whether we run a Debug or Release build and with debugger attached or not: more speed means more errors.

The code shown represents something that I can't really easily change. Of course I'd rather perform a series of `Update.Set()` calls, but that's not really an option right now. The `InsertOneAsync()` followed by a `ReplaceOneAsync()` is abstracted by some kind of repository pattern that updates entities by reference. The non-async counterparts of the methods display the same behavior.

A simple `Thread.Sleep(100)` between inserting and replacing mitigates the problem.

When the query fails, and we wait a while and then attempt to query the document again in the code below, it'll be found every time.

```
private static async Task DoesItExist(IMongoCollection<MyDocument> collection, MyDocument document, DateTime oldDateModified)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    var fromDatabaseCursor = await collection.FindAsync(d => d.Id == document.Id && d.DateModified == oldDateModified);
    var fromDatabaseDoc = await fromDatabaseCursor.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (fromDatabaseDoc != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("But it was found!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("And wasn't found!");
    }
}
```

Versions on which this occurs:

- MongoDB Community Server 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.3, 3.4.4 and 3.4.10, all on WiredTiger storage engine
- Server runs on Windows, other OSes as well
- C# Mongo Driver 2.3.0 and 2.4.4

Is this an issue in MongoDB, or are we doing (or assuming) something wrong?

Or, the actual end goal, how can I ensure an insert is immediately retrievable by an update?

Comment: I tried the code you posted but cannot seem to reproduce the situation you saw. What version is the C# driver you used?

Comment: @Kevin good catch, it happens on driver 2.3.0 and 2.4.4. The error rate with those drivers on my current machine (MongoDB 3.4.3) is 1 in 2500 inserts. I don't have to leave the tool running for long to see errors printed.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, I was able to reproduce it as well using Mongo 3.4.4 and 3.6.6-rc3, driver 2.4.4 and C# 4.6.1

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, In addition I've noticed that when I increase the latency to the server the problem becomes much less significant. 11ms seems to fully negate the problem (however it could be less).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReplaceOneAsync returns 0 if the new document is identical to the old one (because nothing changed).

It looks to me like if your test executes fast enough the various calls to DateTime.Now could return the same value, so it is possible that you are passing the exact same document to InsertOneAsync and ReplaceOneAsync.

Comment: Right, so we should check `MatchedCount`, not `ModifiedCount`. I could swear we don't attempt to replace a document when no changes were made to it, but that sounds like an ideal opportunity to add more unit tests around that code.